# Jpa query date and time column concatenation and compare with current date time

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
@Query(select s from Session s where ( datetime(concat(s.startDt,'',s.startTime) ) >= :lDate))
List<Session> getUpcommingSessionList(@Param("lDate")LocalDateTime lDate);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In session table there is date and time column. If I need to compare with datetime value. what is the query?